# Update mysql id column according to timestamp column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I'm wondering if its possible to update all of the mysql table ids column based on `timestamps`?

So, I have table with columns `ID`,`TEXT`,`STAMP`, and **IDs are really out of order**. It's possible to sort table on `STAMP` and then update all of `IDs incremental from 1` (so the oldest entry will have ID of 1) with one single query?

Comment: i would not brother with updating. Create a new table and insert it in order. BUT you will lose your original ID-s. This is not a bright idea....

Comment: Maybe a better idea, I don't really need original IDs, so it's no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE table_name a,(SELECT id,(@newid:=@newid+1) AS d FROM table_name,(SELECT @newid:=0) AS f ORDER BY stamp) AS g SET a.id = g.d WHERE a.id = g.id;
```

i think this will do.

Comment: That really works, great job! Thank you. Great technique for everyone with similar problem. It actually does all the things I needed in one single query.